# Reducir imagen declarada con CSS Responsive

Tags: html, css

Tengo una imagen de fondo de cabecera, en este caso he colocado una de ejemplo pero para la iamgen real necesito que se vea un poco mas pequeña pero que siga ocupando todo el ancho de la web. Como podría lograr que se viera así? siempre respetando el tamaño responsive?Me explico tal vez la imagen al verse es como que se agranda y se ve demasiado grande, necesito reducirla un poquito para que se visualice mejor.

```css
.cabecera-contacto {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548222606-6c4f581fd09d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1197&q=80");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
        <div class="row cabecera-contacto align-middle">
            <h1>contacto</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: Puedes probar añadiendo `max-width:80%;` a tu `CSS`, o el `%` que necesites...

Answer (score 0):

si quieres que la imagen ocupe todo el ancho disponible usa "100vw" en el ancho. y asegúrate que el reset del navegador ya lo tengas listo, ahora dices que la imagen se ve más grande cuando  la haces mas pequeña no? o viceversa eso se debe a

`background-size:cover;`

Esta propiedad estable el ancho de la imagen al ancho del elemento y como es una imagen se tiene que recortar para que entre ya que su tamaño original es superior por ello se debe recortar para que encaje.

otra cosa es que si intentas hacer mucho mas pequeña o mas grande se distorsionara.

cuando trabajamos con imágenes si intentes hacer mas grande o más pequeña que su tamaño original esta perderá calidad y se distorsionara por eso es mucho mejor trabajar con archivos .svg o tener un tamaño de imagen para cada dispositivo.

para solucionar ese problemita puede usar la propiedad

`object-fit:;`

Aquí te dejo una web que explica muy bien esa propiedad.

https://www.desarrollolibre.net/blog/css/la-propiedad-object-fit-en-css